# How to monitor windows server 2003/2008 user logins?

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-server-2008, monitoring, windows-server-2003

I wanna write a program that should perform some tasks automatically if someone logs onto my server.

My questions regarding this are:

- 1) Is there a last login record that
  is set right after a user logs in
  that I can use/monitor for my
  purpose? If not is there something
  similar I can use?
- 2) What's the best way to constantly
  monitor such a value?

Comment: Admin task, all admins should know how to do this. Ask one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your best (and by far safest) bet is to create a service that accepts the SERVICE_CONTROL_SESSIONCHANGE control.

This will allow your service control handler to receive a control whenever a user logs on, logs off, locks the session, and various other options. Look for more info in a link blow.

This is done by creating a service which has the SERVICE_ACCEPT_SESSIONCHANGE flag in the dwControlsAccepted, as following:

```
SERVICE_STATUS ss;
...
ss.dwControlsAccepted |= SERVICE_ACCEPT_SESSIONCHANGE;
```

Followed by:

```
// This lets the service accept the session change ctrls
// The service handle here is received by calling RegisterServiceCtrlHandler
SetServiceStatus(hServiceHandle,
                 &ss);
```

This will allow windows to send SERVICE_CONTROL_SESSIONCHANGE controls to your HandlerEx function, which should look something like this:

```
DWORD WINAPI HandlerEx(DWORD dwControl,
                       DWORD dwEventType, 
                       LPVOID lpEventData, 
                       LPVOID lpContext)
{
   switch (dwControl)
   {
    ...// Regular control handling
       case (SERVICE_CONTROL_SESSIONCHANGE):
            switch(dwEventType)
            {
                case(WTS_SESSION_LOGON):
                    // Handle logon
                break;

                case(WTS_SESSION_LOCK):
                    // Handle lock
                break;
                ...
            }
       break;

       ...
   }
}
```

You can read up on all the different session change notifications you can receive from here: [WM_WTSSESSION_CHANGE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383828%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), all the notifications you'll need are in the wParam part of the description.

Well, that's the gist of it anyway. You can read more info on the handlerex function here: [HandlerEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683241%28VS.85%29.aspx) and more information about services in general here: [Service Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms685942%28v=VS.85%29.aspx). I suggest you read up on the ServiceMain function, RegisterServiceCtrlHandler function and, most importantly, read the examples posted on the MSDN pages. They're super helpful.

Good luck!